# C++ open() not working for any apparent reason

Tags: c++

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("BONUS.txt");

string info;

    if (!infile)
        cout << "File Open Failure" << endl;
    else
    {
        while (infile >> info)
            cout << info << endl;
            infile.close();
    }
```

This is my code. And no matter what I do, my file always fails to open. It enters the if and exits. What could possibly be the problem? My text file is saved in the correct directory and nothing seems to be wrong with it.

Comment: If you are launching from an IDE the current directory may not be what you think it is.  As a test try a full path to the file.

Comment: Where is the file located?

Comment: [Put `perror()` in the `if` body](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror) to print out why the file wasn't opened. If that doesn't explain what went wrong, edit your question and add the `perror` output. Someone here can probably help you interpret the message.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parameters in `open()`, file to be opened and mode. The mode refers to what you can do with that file, i.e. write to, read from, etc.

There are six possible modes when using `open()`:

1. Parameter `in` stands for input. The [internal stream buffer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/rdbuf/) enables input. (Use for reading the file.)
2. Parameter `out` stands for output. The [same internal buffer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/rdbuf/) enables output. (Use for writing to the file.)
3. Parameter `binary` allows all operations to be done in binary, instead of text.
4. Parameter `ate` stands for `at end` and begins output at the end of the file.
5. Parameter `app` stands for `append` and output events happen at the end of the file.
6. Parameter `trunc` stands for `truncate`. All contents in existence before it is opened are deleted.

It seems that you want to write to the file, in which case use `out`.

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("BONUS.txt", out);
```

If you are not using the correct mode, the function will fail. If you have any more questions, Google `fstream::open()`.